# Trying to make a BMI Calculator on JS, the calculation always returns 'NaN'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a BMI Calculator on JavaScript. I'm facing a problem with the calculation itself. It always returns 'NaN'. I tried to use parseInt(), parseFloat(), and Number(), but it didn't work. I know my problem is in my 'imc' variable because when I put numbers instead of 'height' and 'weight', it doesn't returns 'NaN' anymore, but I don't know what exactly is the problem. Also, I don't have any errors in the console. Can anyone help me, please?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<html lang="fr">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Calculateur d'IMC</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="imc.css">

  <script src="imc.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Calculateur d'IMC</h1>

<h2>Bienvenue! Entrez vos informations ci-dessous pour calculer votre IMC.</h2>

<div id="calcul">
    <h3>Poids:</h3>
    <input type="number" id="weightInput" placeholder="Votre poids..."></input>

    <h3>Taille:</h3>
    <input type="number" id="heightInput" placeholder="Votre taille..."></input><br/>
</div>

<button onclick="calculate()" id="button1">Calculez!</button>

<div id="result"></div>

</body>

<script src="imc.js"></script>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var height = document.querySelector('#heightInput'.value);

var element = document.querySelector('button');


function calculate() {
    let imc = (weight / (height) **2);
    console.log(imc);
    alert('Vous avez un IMC de ' + imc + '!');
    return imc;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Should be `document.querySelector('#heightInput').value;`

Comment: Also if your code has the same mistake for `weight` that should also be fixed.

Comment: Also you should probably get the weight and height **inside** the `calculate()` function so that you get fresh values.

Comment: It works! Thanks! It was ```document.querySelector('heightInput'.value)``` because when I write it like you, in the console an error appears: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')```

Comment: Well if that code runs *before* the HTML is parsed, the element will not be available. If you put the code inside the function, then that will help a lot.

Comment: Yes you're right! The error was still here because I forgot to delete the previous variables haha. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to figure out why it prints out NaN but i fixed it and it seems to work fine

```
var element = document.querySelector('button');


function calculate() {
    var height = new Number(document.getElementById("heightInput").value);
    var weight = new Number(document.getElementById("weightInput").value);
    let imc = (weight / (height) **2);
    console.log(imc);
    alert('Vous avez un IMC de ' + imc + '!');
    return imc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the core problem is the *order of execution*. Your script loaded first and then executed immediately. During its execution it tried to get access to some DOM elements before DOM was ready to operate with. Try to logging variable values in your script and you see.

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.querySelector('button');


function calculate() {
    var height = new Number(document.getElementById("heightInput").value);
    var weight = new Number(document.getElementById("weightInput").value);
    let imc = (weight / (height) **2);
    console.log(imc);
    alert('Vous avez un IMC de ' + imc + '!');
    return imc;
}
```